# How to use GA4 to track page specific sales data

Tags: google, google-analytics, data

We are an e-commerce website and we want to track conversion data for category pages using GA4 campaign data tracking.

For example, sales data of users who went through Category1, Category2, Category3 pages and then made a successful purchase.

Currently we can only track sales data for products, how do I set this up for the tracking of category page?